# How to access a json child in php respect validation?

Tags: php, json, validation, respect-validation

I'm trying to validate the following json file but I can't find the way to access the "Address" child, how should I do it? Everything goes fine until it tries to access the "address" field.

Json:

```
{
"first_name": "Test",
"last_name": "Test",
"email": "test@gmail.com",
"mobile_phone": 123456789,
"address": {
    "country": "Test",
    "postal_code": "Test",
    "city": "Test",
    "street": "Test",
    "number": "Test",
    "floor": "Test",
    "door": "Test"
},
"password": "Test",
"birth_date": "2005-12-30"
}
```

Code:

```
$data = $this->validator->validate($request, [
        "first_name" => v::stringVal()->notEmpty(),
        "last_name" => v::stringVal()->notEmpty(),
        "email" => v::notEmpty()->email(),
        "mobile_phone" => v::intVal()->notEmpty(),
        "address" =>[
            "country" => v::stringVal()->notEmpty(),
            "postal_code" => v::stringVal()->notEmpty(),
            "city" => v::stringVal()->notEmpty(),
            "street" => v::stringVal()->notEmpty(),
            "number" => v::stringVal()->notEmpty(),
            "floor" => v::stringVal()->notEmpty(),
            "door" => v::stringVal()->notEmpty(),
        ],
        "password" => v::base64()->notEmpty(),
        "birth_date" => v::date()->notEmpty()
    ]);
```

Comment: @wp78de Not really, but after fighting against that for a lot of hours I found the right answer, sharing it in a minute.

Comment: But I see you are using the `key` and chaining syntax I have suggested, so it was probably somewhat helpful?

Comment: yes a little bit^^ thank you

Comment: I am glad my help proofed to be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the way to access the child of the json:

```
$this->validator->validate($request, [
        "first_name" => v::stringVal()->notEmpty(),
        "last_name" => v::stringVal()->notEmpty(),
        "email" => v::notEmpty()->email(),
        "mobile_phone" => v::intVal()->notEmpty(),
        "address" => v::notEmpty()
            ->key("country", v::stringVal()->notEmpty())->key("postal_code", v::stringVal())->key("city", v::stringVal()->notEmpty())->key("street", v::stringVal()->notEmpty())->key("number", v::stringVal())->key("floor", v::stringVal())->key("door", v::stringVal()),
        "password" => v::base64()->notEmpty(),
        "birth_date" => v::date('d/m/Y')->notEmpty()
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using Respect\Validation\Validator. We can make use of chained validation and the [`Key`](https://respect-validation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rules/Key/) function to validate sub-arrays as shown in the [docs](https://respect-validation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/feature-guide/).

> ```
> $data = [
>     'parentKey' => [
>         'field1' => 'value1',
>         'field2' => 'value2'
>         'field3' => true,
>     ]
> ];
> ```
>
> Using the next combination of rules, we can validate child keys.
>
> ```
> v::key(
>     'parentKey',
>     v::key('field1', v::stringType())
>         ->key('field2', v::stringType())
>         ->key('field3', v::boolType())
>     )
>     ->assert($data); // You can also use check() or validate()
> ```

Applied to your data, the validation could look like this:

```
use Respect\Validation\Validator as v;

$json = json_decode('{
    "first_name": "Test",
    "last_name": "Test",
    "email": "test@gmail.com",
    "mobile_phone": 123456789,
    "address": {
        "country": "Test",
        "postal_code": "Test",
        "city": "Test",
        "street": "Test",
        "number": "Test",
        "floor": "Test",
        "door": "Test"
    },
    "password": "Test",
    "birth_date": "2005-12-30"
    }', true);
    
v::create()
    ->key('first_name', v::stringType()->length(1, 32))
    ->key('last_name', v::stringVal()->notEmpty())
    //->..
    ->key('address',
        v::key('country', v::stringType()->length(1, 32))
        ->key('postal_code', v::stringType()->length(1, 32))
        ->key('city', v::stringType()->length(1, 32))
        //->..
    )
    ->key('password', v::stringVal()->notEmpty())
    ->key('birth_date', v::stringVal()->notEmpty())
    ->assert($json); // You can also use check() or validate()
```